# recursively search a string in multiple collections against all fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation

**I want to recursively/deeply search a string in all fields of multiple collections.**
As a first step to perform deep search I aggregated all data from multiple collections using the `$lookup` aggregate function.

Here's an example of what I tried so far:

Let's say we have 3 collections

collection1: users

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(bcd13), 
 "email" : "abc@example.com", 
 "name": "abc", 
 "password": "abc.90" 
}
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(abc1234), 
 "email" : "xyz@example.com", 
 "name": "xyz", 
 "password": "xyz_.123" 
}
```

collection2: skills

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(ghj78), 
 "user_id" : "bcd13", 
 "skills": ["React", "PHP", ".Net"] 
}
```

collection3: experiences

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(tyu67), 
 "user_id" : "bcd13", 
 "experiences": [
  {"organization": "Microsoft", "from": "2020-03-10", "to":"present"}, 
  {"organization": "Meta", "from": "2018-01-20", "to":"2020-03-10"}
 ] 
}
```

To perform deep search first of all I aggregated the above data using below aggregation pipelines:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      user_id_string: {
        $toString: "$_id",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "skills",
      localField: "user_id_string",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "skills",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$skills",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "experiences",
      localField: "user_id_string",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "experience",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$experience",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
])
```

The result of above aggregation pipelines looks as follows:

```
[{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(bcd13), 
 "email" : "abc@example.com", 
 "name": "abc", 
 "password": "abc.90" 
 "skills": { 
     "_id" : ObjectId(ghj78), 
     "user_id" : "bcd13", 
     "skills": ["React", "PHP", ".Net"] 
    }
 "experience": { 
     "_id" : ObjectId(tyu67), 
     "user_id" : "bcd13", 
     "experiences": [
      {"organization": "Microsoft", "from": "2020-03-10", "to":"present"}, 
      {"organization": "Meta", "from": "2018-01-20", "to":"2020-03-10"}
     ] 
    }
}
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId(abc1234), 
 "email" : "xyz@example.com", 
 "name": "xyz", 
 "password": "xyz_.123" 
}]
```

Once we get the aggregated data from multiple collections now I want to perform a deep search in this aggregated data against a single string.

My search strings could looks like this:

```
React developer with 2 years of experience.
dot net developer in California.
```

...etc

So with these search strings I should be able to perform deep search in aggregated data against all fields with the keywords in search strings. I tried many ways like `$redact, $graphLookup, $match` but nothing solved the problem and now I am overwhelmed with the information. Can anyone help me with the next aggregate pipeline that I should use next and how to use that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if a [Wildcard Text Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) for each collection would perform well for searches.  Note that there are some insertion/update performance considerations for large text indexes.

Comment: I don't think there is simple way to achieve what you want if your search strings do not share a standard format. Basically you are doing a NLP task, which is likely unachievable with MongoDB query alone.

Comment: try with this method: https://softans.com/question/recursively-search-a-string-in-multiple-collections-against-all-fields/#comment-490

Answer (score 1):

The "skill" and "experience" collection contain user_id, which means they belongs to the user. The best practice in MongoDB is to save them together as one collection instead of 3 collections.

After you put them together, you can choose whether using legacy Text Search on multi fields or directly using Atlas Search.

Regards

Comment: Putting the information into the same collection is a good start. It would be better if you can add more details on how can you combine the information together to be searchable with the input OP provided. Says the phrase *2 years of experience*, we might need extra processing on the start and end date of experiences. Another example is *dot net*. How can we make it recognizable by the query since the document provided by OP is `.Net`